# Save JsPdf generated pdf in a particular location

Tags: jspdf

I want to save the generated pdf in public/uploads how can I do this ?

I know doc.save('pdfname'); but this is not i want.

Answer (score 1):

Is "public/uploads" a server-side location? It looks so at least. jsPDF works client-side, therefore if you want to upload the generated PDF to your server you'll need to perform an Ajax POST request.

Something like this (written on the run, ie untested):

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
// do jsPDF-stuff
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://yoursite.com/public/uploads/');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
   // ....
};
var data = doc.output('arraybuffer');
xhr.send(data);
```

Obviously you'll also need some server-side script to receive and process the PDF.